# Why is my 1-hidden layer neural network with ReLUs not getting more that 18% accuracy on the notMNIST dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow

I'm following Google's deep learning course on Udacity. Assignment 2 is to turn a logistic regression network into a 1-hidden layer neural network with rectified linear units and 1024 hidden nodes using Tensorflow.

To do this I've change this:

```
logits = tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights) + biases
```

into this:

```
logits = tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights1) +
biases1), weights2) + biases2`
```

Here is the full code:

```
def accuracy(predictions, labels):
  return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
          / predictions.shape[0])


batch_size = 128

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    # Input data. For the training data, we use a placeholder that will be fed
    # at run time with a training minibatch.
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                      shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    # Variables.
    weights1 = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, 1024]))
    biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1024]))
    weights2 = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([1024, num_labels]))
    biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))

    # Training computation.
    logits = tf.matmul(tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights1) + biases1), weights2) + biases2
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf_train_labels, logits=logits))

    # Optimizer.
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

    # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.
    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(
        tf.matmul(
            tf.nn.relu(
                tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights1)
                + biases1),
            weights2) + biases2)
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(
        tf.matmul(
            tf.nn.relu(
                tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights1)
                + biases1),
            weights2) + biases2)


num_steps = 3001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  print("Initialized")
  for step in range(num_steps):
    # Pick an offset within the training data, which has been randomized.
    # Note: we could use better randomization across epochs.
    offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
    # Generate a minibatch.
    batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
    # Prepare a dictionary telling the session where to feed the minibatch.
    # The key of the dictionary is the placeholder node of the graph to be fed,
    # and the value is the numpy array to feed to it.
    feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
    _, l, predictions = session.run(
      [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    if (step % 500 == 0):
      print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
      print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
      print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(
        valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
  print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Initialized
Minibatch loss at step 0: 208.975021
Minibatch accuracy: 11.7%
Validation accuracy: 10.0%
Minibatch loss at step 500: 0.000000
Minibatch accuracy: 100.0%
Validation accuracy: 10.2%
Minibatch loss at step 1000: 0.000000
Minibatch accuracy: 100.0%
Validation accuracy: 14.6%
Minibatch loss at step 1500: 0.000000
Minibatch accuracy: 100.0%
Validation accuracy: 10.2%
Minibatch loss at step 2000: 0.000000
Minibatch accuracy: 100.0%
Validation accuracy: 17.7%
Minibatch loss at step 2500: 2.952326
Minibatch accuracy: 93.8%
Validation accuracy: 26.6%
Minibatch loss at step 3000: 0.000000
Minibatch accuracy: 100.0%
Validation accuracy: 17.5%
Test accuracy: 18.1%
```

It looks like it's overfitting. It gets close to 100% accuracy on the training data, but only gets around 20% accuracy on the validation and testing data.

I'm confused because I've seen others on Udacity's forum say that they're getting over 90% accuracy using this method. So I think I might be implementing the network incorrectly.

Is this the proper way to implement a 1-hidden layer neural network with rectified linear units? If so, what do you think I'm doing wrong here?

Thank You

Comment: The method by itself doesn't guarantee any particular accuracy level.  It depends on your data and how well separated the classes are.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I'm using the same dataset as the Udacity lesson, the notMNIST dataset. Is there a way that I can check how well separated the classes are without sifting through tens of thousands of images?

Comment: What accuracy did they get that was better than yours?

Comment: I read comments of people getting close to 90% accuracy. Also, what I'm getting now is the same accuracy that I got with a simple linear regression network, which leads me to believe I'm doing something wrong. And the validation accuracy is not increasing with training.

Comment: I am not expert enough about your code to tell if you are doing something wrong.  But I don't think you know whether the others are doing it right either.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had not shuffled the data before I ran the network. If any other beginners run into a similar issue, make sure that you shuffle the data before you run your experiment so that you get an even mix of classes in each batch.